# How to move a wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress blog running under www.mydomain.com/blog1. I want to move this to www.mydomain.com/blog2. My blog1 links are indexed by google and I want to setup a 301 permanent redirect for them as-well. How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving WordPress is documented in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress). Follow the steps mentionned there.

As for the redirect, your `.htaccess` should be modified. Try adding these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog1/(.*) www.mydomain.com/blog2/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -> [.htaccess](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F)

Although i never tried this myself,but it should work!